# how to place the following children json response inside another variable?

Tags: php, json, laravel

i am currently working with laravel api and making cms using it. i need json response like this(1st output) but it is shwoing like next output: how can i solve this ?

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "",
    "title": "first",
    "description": "This is the complete body for the CMS page",
    "parentPageId": 0,
    "image": "",
    "metaDescription": "meta ",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "creatorID": null,
    "isActive": 0,
    "children": [
        {
          "title": "first",
          "description": "This is the complete body for the CMS page",
          "image": ""
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

but it is returning this output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "",
    "title": "first",
    "description": "This is the complete body for the CMS page",
    "parentPageId": 0,
    "image": "",
    "metaDescription": "meta ",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "creatorID": null,
    "isActive": 0
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "title": "first",
      "description": "This is the complete body for the CMS page",
      "image": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

my code is

```
public function show($slug)
    {
        try {
            $data = Page::where('slug', $slug)->orWhere('id', $slug)->firstOrFail();
            $sub = Page::select('title', 'description', 'image')->where('parentPageId', $data->id)->get();
            return['data'=>$data, 'children' => $sub];
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->returnJson(false, $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        }
    }
```

how could i get the desired output ?

Comment: `$data['children'] = $sub`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the key of `children` to the `$data`, this maybe solves your issue.

```
public function show($slug)
    {
        try {
            $data = Page::where('slug', $slug)->orWhere('id', $slug)->firstOrFail();
            $sub = Page::select('title', 'description', 'image')->where('parentPageId', $data->id)->get();
            $data['children'] = $sub;
            return ['data'=>$data];
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->returnJson(false, $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also merge two query into single.

**Page model**

```
public function children()
{  
    return $this->hasMany(Page::class, 'parentPageId', 'id');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($slug)
{
    try {
        return [ 'data' => Page::with(['children:title,description,image'])
            ->where(
                fn($query) => $query->where('slug', $slug)
                    ->orWhere('id', $slug)
                )           
            ->firstOrFail()
        ];
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->returnJson(false, $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }
}
```